# How can I add a voice recorder in webpage from user and save it in filefield at django model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am studying for a long on a voice recorder from the webpage and I need that to send this data to the backend.

I don't know how to do that.
If someone can guide me that would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Finally, I found a successful solution to this question.
So, I am keeping it here for my future use and anyone's help.

I found a blog where John Idogun solved the exact problem of mine [here is the link](https://dev.to/sirneij/django-and-ajax-building-a-recording-application-4j0a)
So, if anyone needs a solution can follow this.

Thanks